# Finding solution of a functional equation

Tags: calculus

[image]

try: Notice that we have no information that $f$ is differentiable. If it is, then we can use FTC to obtain 
$$ f'(x) + f(x) + xf(x) - x f(x) = 0  \implies f'(x) + f(x) = 0 $$

and if $y = f(x)$, then we observe that $y' = - y $ and thus $y = f(x) = A e^{-x} $ where $A \in \mathbb{R}$.

My doubt is: How can we prove this $f$ is differentiable so we can differentiate equation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have 
$$f(x)=1-x \int_0^xf(t)dt+\int_0^x tf(t) dt.$$

By the FTC, the RHS is differentiable, since $f(t)$ and $tf(t)$ are continuous.

Comment: Im confused. How would $f$ being continuous implies $f$ differentiable ?

Comment: RHS is differentiable, as f is continuous so LHS also differentiable

Comment: how is RHS differentiable? Any integrable function is continous?

Comment: If $f$ is continuous, then $\int_0^x tf(t) dt$ and $\int_0^xf(t)dt$ are differentiable, by FTC.

Comment: What if we had instead $\int_0^x h(x)f(t) dt $ would this still be differentiable?

Comment: If $h$ is differentiable, yes, since $\int_0^x h(x)f(t) dt=h(x)\int_0^x f(t) dt.$